# The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context error in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url.action

I have the following line of code in an asp.net page:

```
$("#example").editable('<%=Url.Action("UpdateSettings","Admin") %>');
```

In document.read (javascript), but visual studio throwns an error when I try to compile it:

> Error 2   The name 'Url' does not exist in the current context

Any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: Are you using ASP. NET MVC 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of MVC are you using?  Are yo using web forms or razor views?

Razor Syntax

```
$("#example").editable('@Url.Action("UpdateSettings","Admin")');
```

Answer (score 1):

Appranetly identical error over at [asp.net forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1370964.aspx/1?CS0103%20The%20name%20Url%20does%20not%20exist%20in%20the%20current%20context). Do you have system.web.mvc referenced in your app?